# Verb Agreement in "There is/are a stapler and a pencil"

Tags: verb-agreement

There ____ a stapler and a pencil on Mrs. Ford's desk.

I believe I would use the word *is* to match up with *stapler*, but I can't remember why.

Comment: I'm guessing because it's present tense.

Comment: For *there is/are*, followed by a list, the plurality of the verb matches the first item in the list: *there is a table and four chairs; there are four chairs and a table*. (Lots of people use the contraction *there's* for both singular and plural subjects, but some people view this as incorrect.)